Remove default spec settings in R seasonal package
I am using the R seasonal package for seasonal adjustment. By default this will generate an X13 spec file with a fairly wide range of default options, as shown below. I would like to understand the arguments I would need to pass to the seas() function so that only the series{} block and x11 { save = (d11) } get written into the spec file. as shown in the "desired spec file" example below.
library(seasonal)
x <- ts(rnorm(200), start=c(2000,1), frequency=12)
seas(x, x11="", dir="C:\logdir")

Spec file
series{
  title = "iofile"
  file = "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpWIQp46\x132cdc34fb21e3/iofile.dta"
  format = "datevalue"
  period = 12
}

transform{
  function = auto
  print = aictransform
}

regression{
  aictest = (td easter)
}

outlier{

}

automdl{
  print = bestfivemdl
}

x11{
  save = (d10 d11 d12 d13 d16 e18)
}

estimate{
  save = (model estimates residuals)
}

spectrum{
  print = qs
}


Desired spec file
series{
  title = "iofile"
  file = "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpWIQp46\x132cdc34fb21e3/iofile.dta"
  format = "datevalue"
  period = 12
}

x11{
  save = (d11)
}



The tables d10, d11, d12, d13, d16, and e18 are added by default and cannot be removed because they are used by other functions in the package.
To add additional tables, use:
seas(AirPassengers, x11.save = "d5")

The standard way of retrieving additional data is through the series function. This will re-evaluate the model one more time:
m <- seas(AirPassengers, x11 = list())
series(m, "d5")

